# What exacly does NextJS Link component trigger and how to catch that event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I developed a simple navbar that has a JSON as data to dynamically construct its links. Visually, I need to persist the navbar with the current active link/route. I tested out two ways:

**First implementation:**

Menu component:

```
const ToggleMenuHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    clearMenu();
    activateItem(e.currentTarget);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

const MenuItems = MenuContent.map(item => {
    return (
        <NavigationItem key={uuidv4()} {...item} clickHandler={ToggleMenuHandler} />
    );
});
```

Navigation item component:

```
<ListItem onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => props.clickHandler(event)}>
    <Link href={sub.href}>{sub.name}</Link>
</ListItem>
```

I'm sure that `ToggleMenuHandler` function is working properly after debugging it. `activateItem` is the function responsible for styling an item as active. If I remove the `<Link>` component from the navigation item, it works just fine. So I figured my menu component was being remounted, which led me to the second implementation.

**Second implementation**

This one was based on the principle that my menu was being remounted. What I did was to bind the href property of `<Link>` to the `NavigationItem`'s id. That way, by using `router.pathname` I could find the item that should be activated, and the code menu component changed to:

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
    activateItem(document.querySelector(`#${router.pathname}`))
}, []);
```

...and I also removed the `ToggleMenuHandler` from the menu item component. That way, when the page was redicted I would get its path and, with it, find the list item to activate visually. I also debbug the `useEffect` hook and it was working properly. However, it was not activated when the Link was clicked.

**Question:**
What exactly is triggered when a NextJS Link component is clicked, and given the context of this question, how can I handle that event?

Comment: `next/link` needs to wrap an `<a>` element (or a component that wraps an `<a>` itself). You can set an `onClick` callback on the inner `<a>` to handle the click event on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know how the Next.js Link component works but I know that it does not need a click event handler.

Also, there should be an `<a>` tag inside the Link component to work properly as a link according to the docs.

I also have personally experienced if we use another element inside the Link component, it does not work like a link but navigates.